# How does concurrent modification work with coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

I am going through this `coroutines` hands-on tutorial [Coroutines-Channels](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/08_Channels). So there is this task of concurrently fetching contributors and showing intermediate progress at the same time using `channels`, See [Here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/08_Channels#:%7E:text=the%20following%20video%3A-,Task,-Implement%20the%20function)

Below is snippet of the proposed solution

```
suspend fun loadContributorsChannels(
service: GitHubService,
req: RequestData,
updateResults: suspend (List<User>, completed: Boolean) -> Unit) = coroutineScope {

........
.........
val channel = Channel<List<User>>()
for (repo in repos) {
    launch {
        val users = service.getRepoContributors(req.org, repo.name) // suspend function
            .also { logUsers(repo, it) }
            .bodyList()
        channel.send(users) // suspend function
    }
}
var allUsers = emptyList<User>()
repeat(repos.size) {
    val users = channel.receive()  // suspend function
    allUsers = (allUsers + users).aggregate()
    updateResults(allUsers, it == repos.lastIndex) // suspend function
}
}
```

The function `loadContributorsChannels()` is called inside a `coroutine` which is using a `Default dispatcher`.[See here](https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/intro-coroutines/blob/c9a3cd5bcfdd6eeea2a358d54e41faa752b34341/src/contributors/Contributors.kt#L103). I have 2 questions.

1. In the snippet above is `allUsers` being modified concurrently since we are already inside a `coroutine` which is using a `Default dispatcher`?
2. If I change the code sequence like below why do I get incorrect results? How is the code above different from the snippet below?

   ```
   val contributorsChannel = Channel<List<User>>()
   var contributors = emptyList<User>()

   for(repo in repos) { 
       launch {
           val contributorsPerRepo = service
               .getRepoContributors(req.org, repo.name) // suspend function
               .also { logUsers(repo, it) }
               .bodyList()

           contributors = (contributors + contributorsPerRepo).aggregate()
           contributorsChannel.send(contributors)  // suspend function
       }
   }

   repeat(repos.size) {
       updateResults(contributorsChannel.receive(), it == repos.lastIndex) // suspend functions
   }
   ```

Is this because of concurrent modification or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code, the top-level coroutine is the only one using `allUsers`. It is its local state.

In your code, `contributors` is a variable shared by all the coroutines and concurrently updated.

The original code correctly applies the Channel as a synchronization mechanism to fan-in all the concurrent computation into a single coroutine that collects the results and uses them.

Comment: So basically if a variable is local to a single coroutine it cannot be concurrently modified? If this is the case then each coroutine is single-threaded? i.e. inside launch or any other function which creates a coroutine, there is only one thread that updates and works on stuff?

Comment: A local variable doesn't guarantee that its referent is used only from a single coroutine. But if you analyze the code from your post, you'll see that it's indeed used by just the top-level coroutine. This is especially easy to see because it's declared after launching the child coroutine. The code of one coroutine is executed strictly sequentially, whether or not it's executed all on the same thread.